# Using masks in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with designing table structure, and i would like to hear your input. I'm creating a table that should contain around 1-2mil rows, lets call them users, and for each users i need to store around 500 boolean values. Main emphasis with this table is to be fast to read from, there is no emphasis on size or write time. Main queries will be about selecting number of users matching various boolean columns values as true or false.

So here is my question: I have to designs in my mind.

- First comes right to ones mind, I will just have 1 table with 500 columns that are boolean/tinyint and just find results with easy queries filtering with one table. Not sure about speed of this query though, and about MySQL capability of working with so many columns.
- Second is a bit complicated. I though about storing boolean values as flags in mask, so number of columns would be significantly reduced, not sure though about speed when using bitwise operations in SELECT's WHERE.

Have anyone experience around working with such data, and speed comparision between similar methods? Or has anyone better idea how to approach this?

Comment: nonSQL databases, which store the values as JSON or something

Comment: My main input to you is that I use bitwise as permission system. So each of my users have 1 column for permission value that can go from 2 to 2^32 and it's pretty good to work that way.

Comment: Here's the key question: how will you query this table? By user id only? By patterns of boolean values (for example `WHERE a = 1 AND b=0 AND d=1`?  Here's another key question:  Can you ever add another boolean value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should test the two different approaches on sample data on your system.  A "normal" way to store the data in SQL would allocate 1 byte per boolean value.  So, a given record would be about 500 bytes (probably plus some additional overhead).  By bit fiddling, you can put this into 63 bytes or so, with the additional complication of more complicated access.  MySQL can readily handle 500 columns.

Under normal circumstances, the difference would not be so great.  Reducing the size of the records by a factor of 8 reduces the number of pages needed and can be the difference between data fitting in memory or not fitting in memory -- and that can be a significant performance boost.  (Actually, a few million records of 500 bytes each should readily fit into available cache, so this might not be a big difference after all).

On the other hand, you can't really index bits.  So, if you want to improve performance for certain queries using indexes, that option would be more difficult if you pack the bits.

In general, for a handful of flags, the performance gains by backing the bits are probably not worth the added complexity on the access.  However, you have a rather extreme case where bit-packing may be warranted.

Answer (score 2):

Please consider a third option. Its a Little more complicated but can improve performace. You will need 3 tables:

> - Users
> - Permissions
> - PermissionsxUser

Table Users only have the information about users. Your "columns" are translated in rows of Permissions table. Then for each permisions you want to give add a row in PermissionsxUser Table. Of course each table need an ID.

It is also more efficient because you only add records when you grant the specific permission. If Users don't have a record for specific permission ID it is not allowed to do that action.

Comment: I though about this, It seems to be the most "clean" method. I'm concerned about speed here, would it be really faster to work three joined tables instead of single one ?

Comment: You can easily index these 3 tables because there is not boolean fields. User table is index by userID, PermissionTable by PermissionID and PermissionsxUser by both fields. That way you query can be very fast. You can also use IN clause to search for a specific set of permissions. I do this in my system permissions and it Works perfectly.

Comment: You can also use a char ID to indentify permission, wich is a lot easy. In my system a create IDs like This: "System.Articules.ADD" or "Sysmtem.Clients.Delete" to identify what an user can or cannot do.

Answer (score -1):

You can create SQL structure that will emulate this 500 bollean values as 
for example 8 * (64 bits) BIGINT columns.

Each boolean set can be representet as integer. 
So You can group Your booleans as inegers.

If You want ask Your DB for boolean set You have to translate it to integer first.

So in every query You will ask for  8  bigints sets, not for 500 booleans.

It may help. 
Each column should have an index of course.

Example: value 2 for unsigned Integer (4 bits) will be represented as 0010
It may stands for 4 boolean columns which have values, false,false,true,false.

Comment: It will be very hard to find individual bits within the integer with this method. You will need to make bit calculations before query de database.

Comment: You will need to make bit calculations before query database. Its not a problem - For each condition set You have to calculate only 8 big intvalues. It may speed up executing time for query a lot.

Comment: So suppose i need to find users with bits 2, 8, 17, 65, 122 and 222 set to true. How would you do that?

Comment: bits 0-63 for first columns bits 64-127 for second and so on. So 2,8,17 bits as true will produce 2^2 +2^8 +2^17 for first column.  So query will looks like SELECT FROM USERS WHERE column1 = 131332 AND column2....

Comment: Ok. It seems like a lot of work just to filter some permission, althrough it can work. Also if performance its an issue, you have to make a lot of calculation on you code just to get the values to filter database. Again you approach will work but it seems like too much work just to filter permissions.

Comment: But it will speed up a lot during performing query. All depends how often queries are made. Your aproach seems to be the best from thoretical point of view. But in real, it may be very slow.